# Detecting table truncation via change tracking in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with detecting table truncation via change tracking in SQL Server 2008 in the following scenario:

Let's assume that CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION = 10 and we are enabling change tracking for table1.

1. CURRENT_VERSION = 10, MIN_VALID_VERSION(table1) = 10
2. we are adding a new record - now we have: CURRENT_VERSION = 11, MIN_VALID_VERSION(table1) = 10
3. our client app is asking for changes: get me all changes since ver 10 assuming that MIN_VALID_VERSION(table1) >= 10 - everything is fine here, and our app is notified about insertion and remembers current version, which is now 11
4. we are truncating a table - now we have: CURRENT_VERSION = 11, MIN_VALID_VERSION(table1) = 11
5. our app asks for all changes since ver 11 - and there is none but MIN_VALID_VERSION(table1) is not greater then the version we are asking for (11). And the whole table truncation is missed by our app.

I believe the correct behaviour should not only set MIN_VALID_VERSION to CURRENT_VERSION, but also increase CURRENT_VERSION prior this operation. But SQL Server does not increase CURRENT_VERSION - hence my question - how to detect table truncation?

Comment: Well, as a hack you could compare the b-tree root page id's from the alloc unit catalog views before and after. TRUNCATE allocates a new tree.

Comment: As I recall, change data capture uses the log, and `TRUNCATE TABLE` does not log, by design. If you need a truncation to be logged, use `DELETE` instead.

Comment: Well, TRUNCATION is detected by the change tracking facility as it resets MIN_VALID_VERSION. The problem is that this modification is not enough to recognize truncation (or in fact the need for full table reload i.e. cleaning in this situation).

Comment: @usr How can I check/query root page id?

Comment: you have 3 groups of instructions in SQL: DML, DDL and DCL. DML is Insert, delete and Update and those instructions store LOG in database LOG (that's why you can Commit or Rollback them) BUT Truncate is DDL, Data Definition Language, and DDL such as Create, Alter, etc, don't store Log, so you can´t Rollback Nor Track them.

Comment: I've solved it with two truncates and a single insert between.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, TRUNCATE TABLE wont be detected by CHANGE TRACKING in Microsoft SQL Server. [From the docs:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710064.aspx)

> Truncating a table can be performed on a table that has change
>   tracking enabled. However, **the rows that are deleted by the operation
>   are not tracked**, and the minimum valid version is updated. When an
>   application checks its version, the check indicates that the version
>   is too old and a reinitialization is required. This is the same as
>   change tracking being disabled, and then reenabled for the table.

Neither can you detect [TRUNCATE by a trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx):

> TRUNCATE TABLE cannot activate a trigger because the operation does
>   not log individual row deletions

As also mentioned in the comments, using DELETE instead will track the changes, and in your application code you should use DELETE rather than TRUNCATE. (TRUNCATE TABLE also has other side effects, like resetting IDENTITY columns.)